# document.getElementById.value is giving undefinedspan error with span tag

Tags: html, knockout.js

When I am doing `document.getElementById.value` with input tag its giving the correct value

```
<td ><input id="testing" data-bind="value: SPL_ApprovalDetailsObj.TgtSales "> </span></td>
```

But when I am doing the same with span tag its giving "spanundefined" error

```
<td ><span id="testing" data-bind="text: SPL_ApprovalDetailsObj.TgtSales "> </span></td>
```

I am not getting what the problem is.

Comment: can u please give me more detail about your task to be done..

Answer (score 0):

Your input tag must contain the value or text attribute in order to get the value..

like

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
```

Comment: His input is working, but span doesn't. He should use `innerHtml` instead of `value`. Although it's kind of strange to include knockout (and jQuery) and still prefer plain js to work with DOM.